# Why can't we have same return type as . instead as ->?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, operator-overloading

Why we can overload -> and not . operator? Both are member access operator and has same significance. 
I have read some reference from

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot

AND

[Why can operator-> be overloaded manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938545/why-can-operator-be-overloaded-manually)

but still my doubts remains the same why we can overload .operator while not ->?

Is it because -> operator implicitly gets the reference of the returning pointer and thus making the call as the chain calls

```
struct X {
    int foo;
};

struct Y {
    X x;
    X* operator->() { return &x; }
};

struct Z {
    Y y;
    Y& operator->() { return y; }
};

Z z;
z->foo = 42;          // Works!
```

**z->foo = 42; This call is converted to ((z.operator()).opeartor()).operator() and thus value of foo is set to 42.**

If I take this point I still have two more points,

1) why can't .(dot) operator works this way?

2) What if -> operator do not returns the reference to the class Y? Will it be a compilation error in that case?

Comment: The short answer is: because that's what the committee decided. There was at one point a paper that outlined how `operator.` could be overloaded (analogous to overloading `operator->`), but if memory serves it was written after the cutoff for new features for that round of standardization, and I'm not sure it was even formally proposed.

Comment: I think the answer is that `.` isn't really the equivalent (pendant) of the `->` operator. What **can** be overloaded are the dereference operators, which are `operator->()` and `operator*()`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin, I am convinced to what you are saying. Just wanted to know if someone can share logical reason for this. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, you are actually very right when we talk of -> operator we are actually referring to dereference operator rather than member access operator. probably this could be one strong reason for it. Lets see what others have to say on this. Thanks for giving me this view...