# What if -> operator do not return the reference like dot . operator? Will this stop overloading -> operator as well?

Tags: c++, operators, overloading, dot-operator

History: Why we can overload -> and not . operator? Both are member access operator and has same significance.

I have read some reference from

http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#overload-dot

AND

[Why can operator-> be overloaded manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2938545/why-can-operator-be-overloaded-manually)

But still my doubts remains the same why we can overload .operator while not ->?

Is it because -> operator implicitly gets the reference of the returning pointer and thus making the call as the chain calls

```
struct X {
    int foo;
};

struct Y {
    X x;
    X* operator->() { return &x; }
};

struct Z {
    Y y;
    Y& operator->() { return y; }
};

Z z;
z->foo = 42;          // Works!
```

**z->foo = 42; This call is converted to ((z.operator()).opeartor()).operator() and thus value of foo is set to 42.**

Question:- If I take this point I still have two more points,

1) why can't .(dot) operator works this way?

2) What if -> operator do not returns the reference to the class Y? Will it be a compilation error in that case?

Comment: Why don't you try it for yourself?

Comment: you can check, i think yes, it would be error. as about `.`,  the good way to resolve ambiguity, whether `.` is referring the object overloading it, or returned by, is explicitly state it will be always returned object. in that case it will be of limited use, and the whole thing looks shady to me. so i don't think it was a technical reason, but rather "conceptual decision". i may be wrong, though: i remember post on SO people just didn't know how to resolve a problem, but now there are solutions. i doubt that, honestly, as there is no `.`overload  in c#. and no `->` at all, so c++ wins here =)

Comment: Thanks for calling my attention to those two links.  The implied recursion was an important detail of `->` behavior that I should have known but didn't.  However, your question seems strange since it includes links to such good answers for what you are asking.  Do you really need someone to rewrite part of the contents of the links you posted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I only understood how overloading the operator-> works, after reading [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access):

> The expression E1->E2 is exactly equivalent to (*E1).E2 for built-in types. If a user-defined operator-> is provided, operator-> is called again on the value that it returns, recursively, until an operator-> is reached that returns a plain pointer. After that, built-in semantics are applied to that pointer.

To answer your second question...lets look at your example again:

```
struct X { int foo; };

struct Y {
    X x;
    X* operator->() { return &x; } // returns pointer 
};

struct Z {
    Y y;
    Y& operator->() { return y; } // returns reference
};

Z z;
z->foo = 42;          // Works!
```

The call `z->` evaluates to `z.y`. This is not a pointer, thus the recursion continues: `(z.y)->` evalutates to `&(z.y.x)`. This is a pointer, and the resulting expression is `(&(z.y.x))->`.

If you make Zs operator return a pointer, the recursion stops at `&(z.y)` but `Y` doesnt have a `foo` and the compiler will complain.